# постоянно запрашивается getscripts2 на сайте

Tags: nginx

Зарегистрировал домен, и как только настроил его, в логах вижу что каждую минуту с разных айпи с разными реферами стучатся на сайт к какому-то скрипту.
Вот пример ошибок в логах:

```
2019/04/25 11:54:52 [error] 18771#18771: *968 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 83.97.110.197, server: xerxes.ru, request: "GET /getscripts2?&b=c98aecda097f2a52964c89167f60f61d&publisher_id=81c675d4733cd5376ff43d2bc7005e0a&uid=1b10b02d377e8c936434a509e7747005&r=&h=www.google.com&rand=1556193290958&_=1556193290480 HTTP/2.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock:", host: "xerxes.ru", referrer: "https://www.google.com/"
2019/04/25 11:54:59 [error] 18771#18771: *968 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 83.97.110.197, server: xerxes.ru, request: "GET /getscripts2?&b=c98aecda097f2a52964c89167f60f61d&publisher_id=81c675d4733cd5376ff43d2bc7005e0a&uid=1b10b02d377e8c936434a509e7747005&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&h=www.youtube.com&rand=1556193298293&_=1556193295292 HTTP/2.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock:", host: "xerxes.ru", referrer: "https://www.youtube.com/"
2019/04/25 11:55:51 [error] 18771#18771: *975 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 78.85.175.231, server: xerxes.ru, request: "GET /getscripts2?&b=c98aecda097f2a52964c89167f60f61d&publisher_id=81c675d4733cd5376ff43d2bc7005e0a&uid=687b15e9a15b91aa8e54d6bc0d982283&r=&h=e.mail.ru&rand=1556193355156&_=1556193343577 HTTP/2.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock:", host: "xerxes.ru", referrer: "https://e.mail.ru/thread/0:15559335500000000132:500000/"
2019/04/25 11:56:17 [error] 18771#18771: *977 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 188.235.10.69, server: xerxes.ru, request: "GET /getscripts2?&b=c98aecda097f2a52964c89167f60f61d&publisher_id=81c675d4733cd5376ff43d2bc7005e0a&uid=b75f3a00d7c3ac8ba10820b87473fe92&r=&h=yandex.ru&rand=1556189834748&_=1556189832912 HTTP/2.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock:", host: "xerxes.ru", referrer: "https://yandex.ru/"
2019/04/25 11:56:18 [error] 18771#18771: *977 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 188.235.10.69, server: xerxes.ru, request: "GET /getscripts2?&b=c98aecda097f2a52964c89167f60f61d&publisher_id=81c675d4733cd5376ff43d2bc7005e0a&uid=b75f3a00d7c3ac8ba10820b87473fe92&r=https%3A%2F%2Fyandex.ru%2F&h=mail.yandex.ru&rand=1556189836082&_=1556189835338 HTTP/2.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock:", host: "xerxes.ru", referrer: "https://mail.yandex.ru/"
2019/04/25 11:56:42 [error] 18771#18771: *981 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 78.85.175.231, server: xerxes.ru, request: "GET /getscripts2?&b=c98aecda097f2a52964c89167f60f61d&publisher_id=81c675d4733cd5376ff43d2bc7005e0a&uid=687b15e9a15b91aa8e54d6bc0d982283&r=https%3A%2F%2Fe.mail.ru%2Fthread%2F0%3A15559335500000000132%3A500000%2F&h=e.mail.ru&rand=1556193406272&_=1556193393206 HTTP/2.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock:", host: "xerxes.ru", referrer: "https://e.mail.ru/thread/0:15559335500000000132:500000/"
2019/04/25 11:56:52 [error] 18771#18771: *983 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 78.85.175.231, server: xerxes.ru, request: "GET /getscripts2?&b=c98aecda097f2a52964c89167f60f61d&publisher_id=81c675d4733cd5376ff43d2bc7005e0a&uid=687b15e9a15b91aa8e54d6bc0d982283&r=https%3A%2F%2Fe.mail.ru%2Fthread%2F0%3A15559335500000000132%3A500000%2F&h=e.mail.ru&rand=1556193416634&_=1556193410996 HTTP/2.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock:", host: "xerxes.ru", referrer: "https://e.mail.ru/thread/0:15559335500000000132:500000/"
```

Что это и как с этим бороться, первый раз такое вижу.

UPD: за последние 3 дня логов на 40мб...

Comment: Если вопрос только в размере логов, то завести отдельный location в котором выключить логирование и всё. Да и php в нём насиловать не нужно

Comment: Нет, пофиг на логи, надо узнать причину))

Comment: Беглый гуглинг даёт только посты 2015 года

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Судя по всему этот домен [с именем персидского короля](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xerxes) когда-то использовался в качестве источника данных о зеркалах для обхода блокировок. Можно предположить что это было [что-то для сайта Kinogo](https://sohabr.net/habr/post/257647/?version=98286), так как [в коде браузерного расширения](https://habr.com/ru/post/257361/) встречается отсылка к запросу к `/getscripts2` для получения каких-то скриптов, будучи вставленным в `<head>` каждой страницы, на которую заходит пользователь. При этом в параметре `h` указан хост, в который встраивается этот скрипт.

Правильным вариантом в такой ситуации будет просто игнорировать запросы:

```
location = /getscripts2 {
    access_log off;
    expires max;
    return 200 "";
}
```

Ещё одним вариантом будет попросить пользователей удалить расширение:

```
location = /getscripts2 {
    access_log off;
    return 200 "alert('Удалите устаревшее расширение для доступа к онлайн-кинотеатру. Это сообщение будет показываться пока расширение не будет удалено.');";
}
```

Менее корректным вариантом будет использовать эту возможность для запуска каких-то своих скриптов на всех сайтах, которые посещают неудачливые пользователи этого расширения. Это может быть очень неприятно пользователям расширения, но и рискованно для вас: можно попасть [в черный список Google](https://transparencyreport.google.com/safe-browsing/search) и вылететь из поисковой выдачи.

Comment: Я бы вместо 200 отдавал 404 или 410

Comment: Почему это было бы лучше?

Comment: Это честно, файла-то нет. А 410 по идее браузер должен запоминать и не ходить больше. Кстати, заголовки кеширования тоже стоит добавить

Comment: Заголовки кеширования - вещь кажется сама собой очевидная, но добавлю.